# move files from subdirectory into parent folder with same name

Tags: macos, shell

I have several folders for each year and inside of those folders there are files corresponding different stations. Somewhat like this:

```
.
├── 2017.1
│   ├── AAAA.2017
│   ├── BBBB.2017
│   └── CCCC.2017
├── 2018.1
│   ├── AAAA.2018
│   ├── BBBB.2018
│   └── CCCC.2018
└── 2019.1
    ├── AAAA.2019
    ├── BBBB.2019
    └── CCCC.2019
```

What I want to do is to move all of these files into the main directory "."according to their name, so it would be something like this:

```
├── AAAA
│   ├── AAAA.2017
│   ├── AAAA.2018
│   └── AAAA.2019
├── BBBB
│   ├── BBBB.2017
│   ├── BBBB.2018
│   └── BBBB.2019
├── CCCC
│   ├── CCCC.2017
│   ├── CCCC.2018
│   └── CCCC.2019
```

I tried some simple code in which I create the folders and simply move the files according to their station. I was wondering if there was a more "elegant" or simple way of doing it

```
mkdir AAAA BBBB CCCC
for file in 20*/AAAA*; do
        cp "$file" "/Users/admin/Desktop/test/AAAA"
done
for file in 20*/BBBB*; do
        cp "$file" "/Users/admin/Desktop/test/BBBB"
done
for file in 20*/CCCC*; do
        cp "$file" "/Users/admin/Desktop/test/CCCC"
done
```

Comment: What's the pattern for the file names? They all end in `.20XX`, and the new directory name should be everything before that period?

Comment: They end differently, but they start all the same. I mean, you have files that start with AAAA and others that start with BBBB, scattered in different folders. The directories should be named after the first four letters of the files, since there are only five variations there should be only five directories

Answer (score 0):

I suggest while loop solution.

```sh
SRC_DIR=/path/to/dir
DEST_DIR=/tmp

cd "${SRC_DIR}"

find . -type f \
  | while read -r FILE; do
    BASENAME=${FILE##*/}
    mkdir -p "${DEST_DIR}/${BASENAME%.*}" && cp -a $FILE "${DEST_DIR}/${BASENAME%.*}"
  done
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. I had to change the FILE to file because shell was not recognizing it but I do not understand how that DEST_DIR works, since my destination directories are all different. Or am I not understanding the logic behind the script?

Comment: Because from I am understanding from this script it is creating a folder inside of the year folder, or maybe I am not understanding at all